# Characterize this probability problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The problem statement goes like this : "There is a $30\%$ chance that an office will be opened in Tampere. If this happens, Heikki has a $60\%$ chance to be the manager of this office. What is the probability that Heikki will be made manager?"

Can such a problem be cleared with the Kolmogorov axioms and the ensuing theorems? Or do I need to consider this as a conditional probability problem, and if so why?

Comment: Define event $E$ to be the event that the office will be opened.  Define event $F$ to be the event that Heikki is appointed manager.  If Heikki can only be appointed manager of this office, then the probability you seek is $\Pr(E \cap F) = \Pr(E)\Pr(F \mid E)$, where $\Pr(E \cap F)$ is the probability that the office is opened and Heikki is appointed manager of that office and $\Pr(F \mid E)$ is the probability that Heikki is appointed manager if the office is opened.